# how to split a text column into 3 numeric columns

Tags: split, calculated-columns

I have a table with a text column for product identification. But in that product identification column there is a number in the middle I need to do math with.  Product number example: 
AB12345-002-004
I want to do math with the middle number 002 between the hyphens '-'.

I've tried a splitstring function I've come across but it doesn't give me a single row, it returns multiple rows.

---

here is the code I wrote:

```
select (k.int_item_no), k.cust_item_id, cast(k.splitdata as bigint) pkqty
from
(
Select  a.int_item_no, a.Cust_Item_ID, b.splitdata 
from [dbo].[Item Cust] a
cross apply dbo.fnSplitString(a.cust_item_id, '-') as b
) k
```

returning rows like:  ( I need the 12, 14, 12 but have been unable to get just that row.)
SF12441 1479030-12      1479030
SF12441 1479030-12      12
LA52131 1479134-14-1    1479134
LA52131 1479134-14-1    14
LA52131 1479134-14-1    1
PA08225 1481392-012-002 1481392
PA08225 1481392-012-002 12
PA08225 1481392-012-002 2

---

Here is the function (thank you to whomever put this together) that I've tried using.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: int_item_no cust_item_id pkqty

Comment: SF12441 1479030-12 1479030
SF12441 1479030-12 12
LA52131 1479134-14-1 1479134
LA52131 1479134-14-1 14
LA52131 1479134-14-1 1
PA08225 1481392-012-002 1481392
PA08225 1481392-012-002 12
PA08225 1481392-012-002 2